# How can I remove a field from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called `x`. It contains objects with three fields. How can I make another array 
called `xmini` that is the same as `x` but with the field called `c` missing?

```
var  x = [
  { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3 },
  { a : 3, b : 4, c : 5 }
];
```

Comment: I was tempted to answer: `var xmini = [{a = 1, b = 2}, {a = 3, b = 4}];`

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: If all you need is for `c` to come back `undefined`, then you can use protoypal inheritance. `x.map(function(o) { return Object.create(o, {c:{value:undefined}}); });` Totally depends on how you're using the data.

Comment: You don't have an array with three fields but rather an array of objects, each of which has three fields.  Furthermore I corrected your original array/object literal syntax which was just wrong.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I send the data back to the server. Needs to go back without any mention of a field c.

Comment: It's a pity that you won't tell us what you have tried or the problem you are having, but if you are sending it to a server then one would assume that you `JSON.stringify` the array, so simply `JSON.stringify(x, ['a', 'b'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will not affect the original `x` object.

```
var xmini = [],
    tmpObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (var key in x[i]) {
        if (key !== 'c') {
            tmpObj[key] = x[i][key];
        }
    }
    xmini.push(tmpObj);
    tmpObj = {};
}
```

You should try to be more specific about what you have tried and what you are trying to accomplish. Another valid answer to your question (as you phrased it) would be simply: `var xmini = [{a = 1, b = 2}, {a = 3, b = 4}];`, but I assumed you wanted a function to create this new object programmatically without changing the original object and without needing to know anything about the other properties of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why people are being so unpleasant with what is a perfectly good question and presented as such a clean reproducable example. Anyway, here is the answer:

```
// simple answer
const x = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 }
];

let newX = x.map(function(item) {
  return { a: item.a, b: item.b };
});

console.log(newX);
```

Or if we need to extend this a little to be more useful for more complicated applications. Imagine you had a massive object ans wanted to exclude just b and c. We can make use of destructuring and the spread operator. All ES6 I think so wasn't available in the stone age when this question was originally posted.

```
// better flexible answer 
const x = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
  { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 }
];

let newX = x.map(({ b, c, ...rest }) => rest);

console.log(newX);
```

I landed here with the exact same question but was not happy with the provided answer or the manner in which it was provided.